# How to know how many bytecodes a python program executes at runtime

Tags: python, interpreter, bytecode

I want to know if there is an easy way to get the number of python bytecodes which are executed **at runtime**. I know I can modify the source code of the interpreter and get what I want, but it is better that there are some standard APIs or other easy ways.

Comment: Can you please explain it a bit more and what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: @thefourtheye I want to know how many bytescodes a python program executes when the program finishes.

Comment: Do you want sum of sizes of all .pyc files? Or do you need something closely related to dis module?

Comment: @FilipMalczak the number of bytecodes in .pyc is not what I want. I want to know the number of bytecodes which are executed. These two numbers are different since a single bytecode can be executed many times.

Comment: @User I want to know the number of bytecodes which are executed in a python program from the beginning to the end of the execution.

Comment: @User python byte code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get to know the Python byte codes that are executed at run time then use.

```
sys.settrace
```

have a look at the `dis` module. This can tell you which byte code is in which line.

Comment: But settrace doesn't accept an event which can fulfill my requirement.   I need an event such as 'bytecode', and the corressponding callback will be called every time one bytecode is executed.

Comment: Why is line not enough? bytecode -> line. line -> set([bytecodes]).

Comment: You mean I can set a hook for line event and in that hook function I can count how many bytecodes in that line? It seems to be a  solution, but I think it is not very accurate because not all the bytecodes belonging to the same source code line will be executed a time. For example, one source code line may contain many condition control flows.

Comment: Finally, I found a similar way here: http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200804/wicked_hack_python_bytecode_tracing.html